# Geopandas import error in RHEL

Tags: python, anaconda, gis

I have installed the Geopandas in RHEL server also its dependency Rtree.
When i try to import the geopandas it throws the below error

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py3.6.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py3.6.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/geoseries.py", line 13, in <module>
    from geopandas.base import GeoPandasBase, _unary_op, _CoordinateIndexer
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py3.6.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from rtree.core import RTreeError
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py3.6.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rtree/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .index import Rtree
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py3.6.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rtree/index.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py3.6.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rtree/core.py", line 127, in <module>
    rt = ctypes.CDLL(lib_name)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py3.6.5/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libspatialindex_c.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When i look arround the solution i came to know that i have to install the spatial index (https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex/wiki/1.-Getting-Started) I have followed the steps for configuration as provided (http://toblerity.org/rtree/install.html) but still issue is not resolved.
and i am unable to import geopandas and rtree in my python.

PS: I am doing all these installation in python virtual environment which i created.

Any help  would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If possible try a Ubuntu base for it, there you'll have apt-get install python3-rtree
i'm not a 100% sure it'll solve and now i can't test it out.